# ESP8266 reboot loop in "memcpy_P" function

Tags: avr, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, attiny

I'm trying to modify code that was initially designed for Trinket board (ATTiny85). It compiles properly for ESP8266-12E board (NodeMCU1.0). But unit is rebooting when loading image to memory.

Lines with:

```
memcpy_P(palette, imagePalette,  2 * 3);
```

Causing device to be rebooted.

I will be really greatfull if someone will advise me what should be modified to solve it? Code is taken from  [Github](https://github.com/adafruit/Kinetic_POV)

Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_DotStar.h>
#include <SPI.h> // Enable this line on Pro Trinket
typedef uint16_t line_t; // Bigger images OK on other boards


// CONFIGURABLE STUFF ------------------------------------------------------

#include "fire.h" // Graphics data is contained in this header file.

#define LED_DATA_PIN  MOSI
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN SCK
#define SELECT_PIN 3

boolean autoCycle = false; // Set to true to cycle images by default
#define CYCLE_TIME 15      // Time, in seconds, between auto-cycle images

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#if defined(LED_DATA_PIN) && defined(LED_CLOCK_PIN)
// Older DotStar LEDs use GBR order.  If colors are wrong, edit here.
Adafruit_DotStar strip = Adafruit_DotStar(NUM_LEDS,
  LED_DATA_PIN, LED_CLOCK_PIN, DOTSTAR_BRG);
#else
Adafruit_DotStar strip = Adafruit_DotStar(NUM_LEDS, DOTSTAR_BRG);
#endif

void     imageInit(void);
uint16_t readVoltage(void);
#ifdef MOTION_PIN
void     sleep(void);
#endif

void setup() {
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);   // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif

#ifdef POWER_PIN
  pinMode(POWER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(POWER_PIN, LOW); // Power-on LED strip
#endif
  strip.begin();                // Allocate DotStar buffer, init SPI
  strip.clear();                // Make sure strip is clear
  strip.show();                 // before measuring battery


 imageInit(); // Initialize pointers for default image

#ifdef SELECT_PIN
  pinMode(SELECT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif
}

// GLOBAL STATE STUFF ------------------------------------------------------

uint32_t lastImageTime = 0L; // Time of last image change
uint8_t  imageNumber   = 0,  // Current image being displayed
         imageType,          // Image type: PALETTE[1,4,8] or TRUECOLOR
        *imagePalette,       // -> palette data in PROGMEM
        *imagePixels,        // -> pixel data in PROGMEM
         palette[16][3];     // RAM-based color table for 1- or 4-bit images
line_t   imageLines,         // Number of lines in active image
         imageLine;          // Current line number in image
#ifdef SELECT_PIN
uint8_t  debounce      = 0;  // Debounce counter for image select pin
#endif

void imageInit() { // Initialize global image state for current imageNumber
  imageType    = pgm_read_byte(&images[imageNumber].type);
  imageLines   = pgm_read_word(&images[imageNumber].lines);
  imageLine    = 0;
  imagePalette = (uint8_t *)pgm_read_word(&images[imageNumber].palette);
  imagePixels  = (uint8_t *)pgm_read_word(&images[imageNumber].pixels);
  if(imageType == PALETTE1)      memcpy_P(palette, imagePalette,  2 * 3);
  else if(imageType == PALETTE4) memcpy_P(palette, imagePalette, 16 * 3);
  lastImageTime = millis(); // Save time of image init for next auto-cycle
}

void nextImage(void) {
  if(++imageNumber >= NUM_IMAGES) imageNumber = 0;
  imageInit();
}

// MAIN LOOP ---------------------------------------------------------------

void loop() {
  uint32_t t = millis();               // Current time, milliseconds

  if(autoCycle) {
    if((t - lastImageTime) >= (CYCLE_TIME * 1000L)) nextImage();
    // CPU clocks vary slightly; multiple poi won't stay in perfect sync.
    // Keep this in mind when using auto-cycle mode, you may want to cull
    // the image selection to avoid unintentional regrettable combinations.
  }
#ifdef SELECT_PIN
  if(digitalRead(SELECT_PIN)) {        // Image select?
    debounce = 0;                      // Not pressed -- reset counter
  } else {                             // Pressed...
    if(++debounce >= 25) {             // Debounce input
      nextImage();                     // Switch to next image
      while(!digitalRead(SELECT_PIN)); // Wait for release
      // If held 1+ sec, toggle auto-cycle mode on/off
      if((millis() - t) >= 1000L) autoCycle = !autoCycle;
      debounce = 0;
    }
  }
#endif

  switch(imageType) {

    case PALETTE1: { // 1-bit (2 color) palette-based image
      uint8_t  pixelNum = 0, byteNum, bitNum, pixels, idx,
              *ptr = (uint8_t *)&imagePixels[imageLine * NUM_LEDS / 8];
      for(byteNum = NUM_LEDS/8; byteNum--; ) { // Always padded to next byte
        pixels = pgm_read_byte(ptr++);  // 8 pixels of data (pixel 0 = LSB)
        for(bitNum = 8; bitNum--; pixels >>= 1) {
          idx = pixels & 1; // Color table index for pixel (0 or 1)
          strip.setPixelColor(pixelNum++,
            palette[idx][0], palette[idx][1], palette[idx][2]);
        }
      }
      break;
    }

    case PALETTE4: { // 4-bit (16 color) palette-based image
      uint8_t  pixelNum, p1, p2,
              *ptr = (uint8_t *)&imagePixels[imageLine * NUM_LEDS / 2];
      for(pixelNum = 0; pixelNum < NUM_LEDS; ) {
        p2  = pgm_read_byte(ptr++); // Data for two pixels...
        p1  = p2 >> 4;              // Shift down 4 bits for first pixel
        p2 &= 0x0F;                 // Mask out low 4 bits for second pixel
        strip.setPixelColor(pixelNum++,
          palette[p1][0], palette[p1][1], palette[p1][2]);
        strip.setPixelColor(pixelNum++,
          palette[p2][0], palette[p2][1], palette[p2][2]);
      }
      break;
    }

  }

  strip.show(); // Refresh LEDs

delayMicroseconds(900);
if(++imageLine >= imageLines) imageLine = 0; // Next scanline, wrap around

}
```

And fire.h file:

```
// Don't edit this file!  It's software-generated.
// See convert.py script instead.

#define PALETTE1  0
#define PALETTE4  1
#define PALETTE8  2
#define TRUECOLOR 3

#define NUM_LEDS 16

// fire.gif ----------------------------------------------------------------

const uint8_t PROGMEM palette00[][3] = {
  {  88,  80,   3 },
  {  88,  88,  23 },
  {  88,  34,   0 },
  {  88,   4,   0 },
  {  88,  49,   0 },
  {  88,   9,   0 },
  {   0,   0,   0 },
  {  88,  88,  10 },
  {  88,  17,   0 },
  {  16,   0,   0 },
  {  88,   1,   0 },
  {  88,   0,   0 },
  {  88,  68,   1 },
  {  33,   0,   0 },
  {   1,   0,   0 },
  {   7,   0,   0 } };

const uint8_t PROGMEM pixels00[] = {
  0X66, 0X6E, 0X95, 0XC7, 0X05, 0XD9, 0XEB, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0X6E, 0X93, 0XCC, 0X4A, 0X9F, 0X9B, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0X66, 0X93, 0X4C, 0X8D, 0X99, 0XB9, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0X6E, 0XD3, 0X42, 0X39, 0X9B, 0XB9, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0X6F, 0XD5, 0X88, 0XD9, 0X9B, 0XB9, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0X6F, 0XB8, 0X23, 0XDF, 0X9B, 0XBD, 0XE6,
  0X66, 0XE9, 0XA8, 0X2A, 0X9E, 0X9B, 0XBD, 0XF6,
  0X66, 0XE9, 0X32, 0X8B, 0XFE, 0X9B, 0XAB, 0XDE,
  0X66, 0XED, 0X52, 0X5D, 0XE6, 0XFB, 0XA3, 0XB9,
  0X66, 0XFB, 0X22, 0X59, 0XE6, 0XED, 0XA3, 0XAD,
  0X66, 0X9A, 0X24, 0X39, 0X66, 0XEF, 0XA3, 0X3B,
  0X6E, 0XF3, 0X24, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X6F, 0XD3, 0X3B,
  0X66, 0X93, 0X44, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X6E, 0X93, 0X3A,
  0X6E, 0X93, 0X44, 0X59, 0X66, 0X6E, 0X93, 0X5A,
  0X6E, 0X93, 0X2C, 0X59, 0XE6, 0X6E, 0XD3, 0X5A,
  0X66, 0X9A, 0X44, 0X8D, 0XF6, 0XEF, 0XA8, 0X8A,
  0X66, 0XFA, 0X2C, 0X45, 0X9F, 0XFD, 0X52, 0X8B,
  0X66, 0XED, 0X8C, 0X04, 0X5D, 0XD8, 0X44, 0X3D,
  0X66, 0XE9, 0X3C, 0X77, 0XC4, 0X4C, 0XC4, 0XA9,
  0X66, 0X69, 0XAC, 0X71, 0X77, 0X77, 0XC5, 0XBF,
  0X66, 0XEF, 0XB2, 0X71, 0X11, 0X70, 0X2A, 0X9E,
  0X66, 0X6F, 0XD8, 0X01, 0X11, 0X74, 0XA9, 0XF6,
  0X66, 0X6E, 0X93, 0XC1, 0X17, 0XC3, 0XDE, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0X6E, 0XFA, 0X47, 0X17, 0X2D, 0XF6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XBF, 0XFD, 0X50, 0X7C, 0X89, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XBF, 0XFD, 0XA4, 0XCC, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XFB, 0X9F, 0XD8, 0X44, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0X9B, 0XBD, 0X93, 0X22, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XFB, 0XB9, 0X9D, 0X52, 0X5D, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XDB, 0XB9, 0XF9, 0X32, 0X8A, 0XF6, 0X66,
  0X6F, 0XDB, 0XB9, 0XFF, 0XA2, 0X8A, 0X9E, 0X66,
  0XED, 0XBA, 0XB9, 0XE9, 0XB8, 0X23, 0X9E, 0X66,
  0X9B, 0XA3, 0XBF, 0XEE, 0XD5, 0X25, 0XDF, 0X66,
  0X9A, 0X3A, 0XDF, 0X6E, 0X93, 0X28, 0XBF, 0X66,
  0XB3, 0X5B, 0X96, 0X66, 0X93, 0X22, 0XAF, 0XE6,
  0XB3, 0X3D, 0XE6, 0X6E, 0X93, 0X24, 0X39, 0XE6,
  0XA3, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X66, 0X93, 0X42, 0X39, 0XE6,
  0XA5, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X6E, 0X93, 0X44, 0X39, 0XE6,
  0XA5, 0X3D, 0XE6, 0X66, 0XD5, 0X44, 0XA9, 0X66,
  0XA8, 0X8A, 0X96, 0X6F, 0XD2, 0X44, 0XAF, 0X66,
  0XB8, 0X25, 0XD9, 0XFD, 0X3C, 0XC8, 0XAF, 0XE6,
  0XD5, 0X44, 0X5D, 0XD3, 0XC0, 0X08, 0XDE, 0X66,
  0X9A, 0X20, 0XC4, 0X4C, 0X77, 0XC3, 0XDE, 0X66,
  0XFB, 0X8C, 0X77, 0X71, 0X71, 0X43, 0XFE, 0X66,
  0XE9, 0XA2, 0X01, 0X11, 0X17, 0X4B, 0XF6, 0X66,
  0X6E, 0XDA, 0X47, 0X11, 0X17, 0X8D, 0XF6, 0X66,
  0X66, 0XE9, 0X3C, 0X11, 0X1C, 0X39, 0XE6, 0X66,
  0X66, 0X6F, 0XD2, 0X71, 0X74, 0XAF, 0XEE, 0X66 };

typedef struct {
  uint8_t        type;    // PALETTE[1,4,8] or TRUECOLOR
  line_t         lines;   // Length of image (in scanlines)
  const uint8_t *palette; // -> PROGMEM color table (NULL if truecolor)
  const uint8_t *pixels;  // -> Pixel data in PROGMEM
} image;

const image PROGMEM images[] = {
  { PALETTE4 ,   48, (const uint8_t *)palette00, pixels00 }
};

#define NUM_IMAGES (sizeof(images) / sizeof(images[0]))
```

Error code: (I have added Serial.Print information before each line of code that way I know there is someting with memcpy_P)

```
Loading pgm_read_byte... OK ! 
Loading pgm_read_word... OK ! 
Loading PALETTE1 memcpy_P... 
Exception (28):
epc1=0x40202fda epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x000078ec depc=0x00000000

ctx: cont 
sp: 3ffef830 end: 3ffefa40 offset: 01a0

>>>stack>>>
3ffef9d0:  3ffe8910 3ffee7d0 00000001 402022d6  
3ffef9e0:  00000000 00000001 3ffee9ec 3ffe8910  
3ffef9f0:  3ffee7c4 3ffe88ec 3ffee9ec 40201ff9  
3ffefa00:  0001c200 0000001c 3ffee7d0 3ffeea10  
3ffefa10:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee7d0 40202051  
3ffefa20:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffeea08 40202d60  
3ffefa30:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffeea20 4010070c  
<<<stack<<<
```

Decoded error with avr decoder:

```
Exception 28: LoadProhibited: A load referenced a page mapped with an attribute that does not permit loads
Decoding 6 results
0x40202fda: pgm_read_byte_inlined at C:\Users\Rafal\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc2\cores\esp8266/pgmspace.h line 104
0x402022d6: Adafruit_DotStar::sw_spi_out(unsigned char) at D:\Dropbox\ArduinoLib\libraries\Adafruit_DotStar/Adafruit_DotStar.cpp line 40
0x40201ff9: imageInit() at D:\Dropbox\ArduinoLib\sketch_nov16b/sketch_nov16b.ino line 167
0x40202051: setup at D:\Dropbox\ArduinoLib\sketch_nov16b/sketch_nov16b.ino line 125
0x40202d60: loop_wrapper at C:\Users\Rafal\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc2\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 57
0x4010070c: cont_norm at C:\Users\Rafal\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0-rc2\cores\esp8266/cont.S line 109
```

BTW. I have tried multiple versions of boards 2.3.0, 2.4.0 RC1 and RC2.

Comment: How do you know that specifically the named line is causing the reboot?

Comment: Maybe it's not right way to do it but I have enabled serial.print information for each line and program is resetting before those "memcpy_P" lines.

Comment: From the stack trace, the error seems to come from `Adafruit_DotStar::sw_spi_out(unsigned char)` and not your own code...

Comment: Which again seems to be called from `imageInit()` which your code does not seem to call, which makes me believe that your source code does not match the binary causing the exception.

Comment: why is this tagged "avr" and "attiny" ?? What do you call "avr decoder" ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the adafruit code you posted above working with ESP8266 by deleting all of the instances of PROGMEM from the sketch. Just use find and replace function in arduino and delete all progmem and replace with nothing. Then replace imageinit with the one below from the supernova sketch. It does work but it stores all the patterns in working memory, not in flash. I am now trying to get patterns stored in flash so more patterns can be stored.

```
void imageInit() { // Initialize global image state for current imageNumber
  imageType    = images[imageNumber].type;
  imageLines   = images[imageNumber].lines;
  imageLine    = 0;
  imagePalette = (uint8_t *)images[imageNumber].palette;
  imagePixels  = (uint8_t *)images[imageNumber].pixels;
  // 1- and 4-bit images have their color palette loaded into RAM both for
  // faster access and to allow dynamic color changing.  Not done w/8-bit
  // because that would require inordinate RAM (328P could handle it, but
  // I'd rather keep the RAM free for other features in the future).
  if(imageType == PALETTE1)      memcpy_P(palette, imagePalette,  2 * 3);
  else if(imageType == PALETTE4) memcpy_P(palette, imagePalette, 16 * 3);
  lastImageTime = millis(); // Save time of image init for next auto-cycle
}
```